# I would like a script to search within text files a certain pattern of strings and move those files to another directory

Tags: text, batch-file, full-text-search, notepad++

I need to know how to perform an advanced search on a text file using  tools like notepad++, freecommander and windows if possible. A bat script file will be great.

The problem is that i need to search through about 1000 txt files in a directory. I need to know form those 1000 txt files which have a string in the form of for example "SYR_SHA/245/4". I just want it search for the pattern for example `*****_******/*****/******` where `*` are characters that can change in number.

There must be an `_` between the first and second set of characters as seen above in the example.
the script should go through the entire txt file and search for the above pattern. The script should then Move all the results in to a seperate directory

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create this batch file and copy it into your folder where you have all the 1000 .txt files

Change  the `yourdestinationdirectory` directory and run the batch file

```
@Echo Off
FindStr /M /R "[a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*" *.Txt > findstr.out
For /F "tokens=*" %%a In (FindStr.out) Do call :move_Rtns %%a
del FindStr.out
Exit /B

:move_rtns
copy %1 yourdestinationdirectory\*
del /Q %1
Exit /B
```

Please change the Regex according to your requirement, for eg. If you are expecting number and letter together you can replace `[a-zA-z]` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Good luck